# Show name of custom patterns in GIMP

Tags: gimp, patterns

I'm creating a set of custom patterns with GIMP. When I import them I would like to have their names below the filter field, as the default ones have:

[image]

However, GIMP only shows a `#1`-like string:

[image]

I need to see the names of my patterns because they are bigger then the default ones and some of them are very similar to other ones, so I can't recognize them very well using only the icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how you produce them...

- Exported as a .PAT, you have to give a name which is used
- Exported as a PNG, either:

  - image has a comment (see Image>Properties), and the comment is used
  - image has no comment and the filename is used

In any case you can easily filter your images: instead of putting them directly in the `patterns` directory, create a subdirectory and put them there. Then you can filter them using the filter at the top of the list, the name your directory will appear as a possible "tag":

[image]

Comment: I export them as .PAT files. When you say to "give a name which is used" you are talking about the filename?

Comment: When you export as a pattern you have to give a name in the dialog (at least in 2.10). We are talking about Gimp's .PAT and not Photoshop .PAT, right (same extension, two different formats).

Comment: Yes, I'm working with GIMP 2.10.8. I wrote the pattern name in the dialog but GIMP still doesn't show it.

Comment: Did you refresh the list?

Comment: Yes, first thing I tried. Anyway, I think I found out what the problem was. I was using the portable edition in Windows: I tried the normal one and everything works well; in Ubuntu it's fine too. I suppose the portable version was making a mess.